# Where to put glogon.sql in 32-bit ODAC (11.2.0.2.1)?

Tags: oracle

I installed the 32-bit  ODAC (11.2.0.2.1) from [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/downloads/utilsoft-087491.html). The  Oracle Universal Installer version contains Oracle SQL*Plus 11.2.0.2.0. But I'm missing the sqlplus/admin/ folder in the installation, where I usually put the glogin.sql file.

**Edit:**

This install is on a new Windows 7 - 64 bit Notebook, which is my first 64-bit Windows system.

The initial idea is not to install any Oracle server there, but I guess I'll change my mind about this during the first 2 month.

I find sqlplus.exe in the folder D:\app\berndk\product\11.2.0\client_1.

BTW This install has no sqlplus subfolder and the ORACLE_HOME environment varaiable is not set. As I do not need ODBC that install generally works quite well.

Comment: Can you use [login.sql](http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/ora/sqlplus/login.html) instead?

Comment: Is this an Oracle server or a client PC?

Comment: It is a client on my new Windows 7-64 bit notebook.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to the [link](http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/ora/sqlplus/login.html) provided by Jack Douglas, I found the solution.

I needed to create a login.sql file in the same folder as sqlplus.exe **and** I had to set the SQLPATH environment variable to this path.

From the article I got the impression, that setting the variable was not necessary.